# How to display the social media icons on the top-right in mobile phone view?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, icons

I have my social media icons in a top-right position both in laptop and tablet view but when I jump on mobile phone view, after clicking the toggle, they are listed vertically together with the main nav (home, contact etc), instead I want them to remain on a top-right position.
I know there is something wrong with the code (I'm using bootstrap3) but I don't know how to change it.
Please can anyone help me as I'm quite new with this, thanks.

**Tablet view**

[image]

**Mobile phone view**

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allerta Stencil' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous"> @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Bio", "About", "Home")</li>
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Portfolio", "Portfolio", "Home")</li>
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="mailto:" target="_blank"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here the basic CSS for mobile phone view:

```css
@media all and (max-width: 767px) {

 .nav > li {             
     border-right: none;  
 }

 .navbar-nav > li > a {
     padding-top: 8px;
     padding-bottom: 15px;     
 }

.navbar-right > li > a {
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;  
}

.nav {
    background-color: #008060;        
}

}
```

Comment: Your problem seems not related to ASP.NET so I suggest to replace`@Html.ActionLink` and `@Styles.Render` with proper tags. And where is your CSS? Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your CSS, it can be tough to troubleshoot, but the "top right" isn't part of your collapsible nav bar so nesting your social icons inside `navbar-collapse collapse` isn't going to grant the results you want.

```
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Bio", "About", "Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Portfolio", "Portfolio", "Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="mailto:" target="_blank"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Without seeing your CSS, I won't make assumption based changes, but I will recommend you create a new div for your social icons and use flexbox to align left and right.

Comment: I have created a new nav header (floating right) outside navbar collapse and now is working, thank you!

Comment: Consider taking a look at Flexbox as another option. Learn it now, it will save you so much time going forward on layout tweaking. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well a walkaround is add the same li's to navbar-nav and add visible-xs-*,

then add hidden-xs to the ones on right nav bar.

The classes; **hidden-xs** and **visible-xs-*** are both from bootstrap framework.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allerta Stencil' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous"> @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="visible-xs-*"><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
          <li class="visible-xs-*"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
          <li class="visible-xs-*"><a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
          <li class="visible-xs-*"><a href="mailto:" target="_blank"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Bio", "About", "Home")</li>
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Portfolio", "Portfolio", "Home")</li>
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
          <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
          <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
          <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="mailto:" target="_blank"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```